# Client-Server-Client communication using Sockets and Ajax - Java

Tags: java, ajax, websocket

I am try to create small chat application. I refer many websites. All websites give example Client.java and Server.java files and communicate the main methods only. But i need client (UI, Html) send message  and server sockets give response. This same concept how to connect user1 to user2 and how to both are communicate ?